# How to manage MasterPages and Content Pages in different folders

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

In my asp.net application, I've a folder for "MasterPages". All content Pages are outside of this folder.

I don't know how to set Path on masterPages for "Script" files, "Css", "Images" etc.
Please give me a solution to set path on materpages which will work on content pages too.

I don't wanna use hardcoded stuff for this thing. Please give me solution, which will work globally for all masterpages and there content pages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For referencing use a path that starts with "~".

So, if you have a file called style.css in a folder called assets, your path should look like...

```
<link href="~/assets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: It will work for both(master and content)?
could i use same for script files, images etc?